# Can I create non-language based global .resx?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, globalization, resx

So here is the scenario. I have an internationalized application using .NET MVC in English and French using the global resources.

For certain clients using the application, the terminology used to reference an object such as "User" is different. One client might see that User as a "Subscriber" but another client's mental model of the User is a "Lead".

So in my English global resource file, the name and value is simply "User" and now I've failed to satisfy both clients. :)

Is there a way to handle different terminology in the same language using resource files?

I tried to create a new resource file, MyApp.[non-language identifier].resx, but .NET didn't seem to like that at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, though I'm not sure exactly how to do it. This MSDN article has some info on creating a custom culture in .NET:

[How to: Create Custom Cultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx)

It's definitely a scenario that we've tested before while working on ASP.NET (I'm a developer on the ASP.NET team). One of our scenarios was to use the localization feature to help a developer create "branded" versions of their sites, which sounds almost exactly like what you're trying to do.